# How do I override a nested js file in a theme?

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, overrides

I have a custom module that uses a js file defined in:

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/sub/directory/myfile.js`.

Works fine. I want to use a different file within a theme; from the documentation it looks like I should drop the new js file in

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Vendor_Module/web/js/sub/directory/myfile.js`

but it does not seem to be working. After running `setup:static-content:deploy` the `pub/static/etc` directory contains the same `myfile.js` that is in the `Vendor/Module` rather than in the theme. (`pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/Vendor_Module/js/sub/directory/myfile.js`)

How do I override a modules javascript file (contained in a sub directory) in a theme?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use requirejs-config.js to override js files of module :

**Step-1:**
To do this, place requirejs-config.js file in your theme root folder ( same path where your registration.php, theme.xml is placed ) and content will be like :

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "jsmodule-identifier": "js/file-override"
        }
    }
};
```

**Step-2:**
copy js file from module folder and place that file in your theme/**web/js/file-overrid.js** folder

**NOTE** : to verify file mapping identifier, view source of your site html page and check requireis-config.js file